# Two logs for one class

Tags: java, log4j

I'm working on jdk 1.6 and I have a class that needs to log to 2 different log files using log4j. I have read many other answers, but I can't get mine to work the way I want it. This is my log4j properties.

```
log4j.debug=false
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, appLog

log4j.logger.com.my.apps.idm.transactionalemail=DEBUG, appLog, infoLog

log4j.appender.appLog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.appLog.File=/opt/apps/logs/${ni.cluster}/TransactionalEmail/1.0/TransactionalEmail.log
log4j.appender.appLog.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.appLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.appLog.layout.ConversionPattern=DATE: %d{DATE}%nPRIORITY: %p%nCATEGORY: %c%nTHREAD: %t%nNDC: %x%nMESSAGE:%m%n%n

log4j.appender.infoLog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.infoLog.File=/opt/apps/logs/${ni.cluster}/TransactionalEmail/1.0/Info.log
log4j.appender.infoLog.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.infoLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.infoLog.layout.ConversionPattern=DATE: %d{DATE}%nPRIORITY: %p%nCATEGORY: %c%nTHREAD: %t%nNDC: %x%nMESSAGE:%m%n%n
```

And the way I want this to work is like this

```
public class MyClass{
    private static final LOG = Logger.getLogger("appLog");
    private static final INFO_LOG = Logger.getLogger("infoLog");

    public void myMethod(){
        INFO_LOG.debug("This is info");
        LOG.debug("This is debug");
    }
}
```

What happens when I run my app is that the Info.log has the same information as TransactionalEmail.log, and also, the line "This is a test" doesn't show up in either of the log files.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For one thing, you have two `Logger` instances in a class.  `log4j` config allows you to split all logged info into two appenders, which you seem to already know.

Comment: Logger.getLogger() expects the name of a logger. Not the name of an appender. Since you asked for the logger "appLog", and since your config doesn't define any such logger, thr root logger configuration is used. Same for infoLog. You have configured a single logger in your config file: `com.my.apps.idm.transactionalemail`. And using this logger will send ever logged message to both appenders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend against using multiple logger instances for classes.  Utilize log4j's configuration to handle logging events as they are generated.  You may want to look at the [Routing File Appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender) to decide how log events are handled.  From the link

> The RoutingAppender evaluates LogEvents and then routes them to a subordinate Appender. The target Appender may be an appender previously configured and may be referenced by its name or the Appender can be dynamically created as needed. The RoutingAppender should be configured after any Appenders it references to allow it to shut down properly.